# Input shape of initial_state of tf.keras.layers.LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, tf.keras

Here I want to construct a very basic and simple character-wise RNN.

suppose that my dataset is embedded like this:

```
import numpy as np
 batch_1 = np.array([[1, 2, ...., 20], [21, .....,40], [41,....,60], [61,...., 80]])
 batch_2 = np.array([[...], [...], [...], [...]])
import tensorflow as tf
batch_size = 4
steps_number = 20
hidden_units = 100
keep_prob = 0.5
dim = tf.zeros([batch_size, hidden_units])
input_data = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1, steps_number), batch_size=batch_size)
hidden_1, state_h, state_c = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=hidden_units, stateful=True, dropout=keep_prob, return_state=True)(input_data, initial_state=[dim, dim], training=True)
hideen_2 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=hidden_units, stateful=True, dropout=keep_prob, return_state=False)(hidden_1, initial_state=[state_h, state_c], training=True)
hidden3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu')(hidden_1)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(hidden3)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(input_data, output)
```

Here I got this error in the hidden_2 layer:
**ValueError: Shape (100, 4) must have rank at least 3**

The problem is that the output of hidden_1 layer size should be [batch_size, steps_number, hidden_units]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution however, I dont I understand why I have to specify the Input shape  in term of colum array:

> shape=(steps_number,1) instead of (1,steps_number)

```
import tensorflow as tf
batch_size = 4
steps_number = 20
hidden_units = 100
keep_prob = 0.5
dim = tf.zeros([batch_size, hidden_units])
input_data = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(steps_number,1), batch_size=batch_size)
hidden_1, state_h, state_c = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=hidden_units, stateful=True, dropout=keep_prob, return_state=True, return_sequences=True)(input_data, initial_state=[dim, dim], training=True)
print(hidden_1.get_shape().as_list)
hideen_2 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=hidden_units, stateful=True, dropout=keep_prob, return_state=False)(hidden_1, initial_state=[state_h, state_c], training=True)
hidden3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu')(hidden_1)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(hidden3)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(input_data, output)
```

Comment: Because `tf.keras.layers.LSTM` accepts A 3D tensor, `[batch_size, time_steps, num_features]`. Even though OP did not mention explicitly the number of features, you take it as one when you define `shape=(steps_number,1)`.